# Permission denied after giving permission to save a file in another folder

Tags: python

I have created a JSON file in Python and I want to save it in another folder outside of the project. This is the file location where I want to store the JSON:

```
JSON_location = os.getcwd()
JSON_location = JSON_location[0:len(JSON_location)-3] + "/web-traffic/src/Data"
```

I know that if I want to save a file in another folder I have to give it permission to write it there, so I gave it permission and then I tried to save the JSON to that directory:

```
os.chmod(JSON_location,0o777)

json.dump(JSON_dictionary, open(JSON_location,"w"))
```

After I compile the file, I get the error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied". I don't know what I am doing wrong in giving permission to save a file in that folder.

Comment: Does the directory have permissions that allow everyone (meaning the script) to change permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the path you are providing. You are not providing the name of the file you want it to create, therefore it has no permission on editing the whole folder.

Try something like:

```
JSON_location = os.getcwd()
JSON_location = JSON_location[0:len(JSON_location)-3] + "/web-traffic/src/Data/stored_file.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with your path

instead of:

```py
JSON_location = os.getcwd()
JSON_location = JSON_location[0:len(JSON_location)-3] + "/web-traffic/src/Data"
```

use `os.path.join`

```py
JSON_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "/web-traffic/src/Data")
```

and also a potential error with how you store files:

```py
with open(JSON_location, "w") as file:  # It will automatically close the file once the writing to file is done
    json.dump(JSON_dictionary, file)
```